# Adding fixed effects in regressions with cross-sectional data

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model, cross-section

I am working with cross-sectional data that spans 8 years. The data is at the individual level and the treatment variable is at the district level.

I am regressing individual-level outcome (whether an individual is employed or not) on the following variables:

- Treatment binary dummy variable at the district level.
- Individual-level controls like education, age, age squared, and marital status.
- Year fixed effects.
- District fixed effects.

In R, I am using the following code:

```
reg <- lm(employed ~ treat + education + age + age_sq + marital_status + factor(year) + factor(district), data)
```

Is this the correct way to do it for cross-sectional data, by using the lm() function and by adding the factor() functions like that for year and district?

My concern is that when I do not include factor(district), the coefficient on treat is 0.067 (so, the probability of a person in the treatment group being employed is 6.7 percentage points higher than those in the control group), which is highly significant. But when I include factor(district), the coefficient on treat drops to -0.009  (the probability of the person being employed in the treatment group is almost 1 percentage point lower than control group individuals) which is also highly significant. Any idea why there is such a big change after including factor(district)? Due to this, I feel like I am doing something wrong with the R regression formula.